# How to choose the regularization term and why is the ridge regularization term W^2 in linear regression?

Tags: regression, regularization

I am working on implementing linear regression with regularization, and I'm trying to understand how to decide the appropriate regularization term to use. Specifically, I would like to know why in ridge regularization, the term used is W^2.

From my understanding, regularization helps prevent overfitting by adding a penalty term to the loss function. In ridge regression, the regularization term is commonly defined as the sum of squares of the model's weights (W^2). However, I'm uncertain about the rationale behind choosing this particular form of regularization term.

Can someone please explain why the ridge regularization term is W^2 in linear regression? Additionally, I would appreciate any insights or guidelines on how to choose the regularization term in general, taking into account different scenarios or data characteristics.

I expected the regularization term to help prevent the model from excessively relying on any single feature, thus reducing the chance of overfitting.

After training your model, I obtained the results. However, I am confused about the role and significance of the regularization term and how it influenced the outcome.

Comment: from a computational/optimization perspective, w^2 is so popular because the regression problem can be written as $\min_{w} \sum_p (w_p-\tilde{w}_p)^2$ (where $\tilde{w}_p$ is the OLS estimate), so by adding an additional quadratic term, we don't change the from of the loss function and the problem is no harder than standard OLS (and often easier!).

Comment: People usually choose a penalty through cross-validation or by inspecting the [ridge trace plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ridge+trace+plot).